# Vert.x Not Using HttpServerOptions

Tags: java, vert.x

I am setting up a vert.x server and have a route that returns a 204 when posted to. I want to run my server on port 8010, which works when I start vertx like so-

```
vertx.createHttpServer(httpServerOptions).requestHandler(router).listen(8010);
```

This works, and I can post to `http://localhost:8010/foo` and get a `204` response.

But I'd rather using the HttpServerOptions because that's where I'll eventually define certificates/etc. If I use HttpServerOptions I'm unable to post to that same address and get a 204-

```
HttpServerOptions httpServerOptions = new HttpServerOptions();
httpServerOptions.setPort(8010);

vertx.createHttpServer(httpServerOptions).requestHandler(router).listen();
```

Removing `.listen()` doesn't work either.

How do I setup a vertx server on port 8010 from just the HttpServerOptions?

Comment: Your example actually works for me. Please check your code again, as maybe you're not actually setting the options.

Comment: In newer vert.x versions the call for listen is something like:server.requestHandler(router).listen(port); so  server.requestHandler(router).listen(httpServerOptions.getPort()); would do what you want?